# Apollo client MockedProvider: Skip loading state

Tags: typescript, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I've set up a React app with Apollo to have a wrapper component that handles loading data from the network, so that each component underneath can query the data straight from the Apollo cache without having to worry about handling loading states. Thus, my components look like this:

```
export const COUNT_OFF_ADAPTER_QUERY = gql`
  query CountOffAdapterQuery($vampId: ID!) {
    vamp(id: $vampId) @client {
      id
      countingOff
      countingOffStartTime
    }
  }
`;

export const CountOffAdapter: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const vampId = useCurrentVampId();

  const {
    data: {
      vamp: { countingOff, countingOffStartTime }
    }
  } = useQuery<CountOffAdapterQuery>(COUNT_OFF_ADAPTER_QUERY, {
    variables: { vampId }
  });

  const prev = usePrevious({ countingOff, countingOffStartTime });

  const countOff = useCountOff();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Do react stuff
  }, [countOff, countingOff, prev]);

  return null;
};
```

In practice (in the browser), this works really well since in the app Apollo will return the data immediately from the cache so the `loading` result from the `useQuery` call is never `true` and I can destructure the data, use it in subsequent hooks, etc.

HOWEVER, when it comes time to test, it seems that `MockedProvider` *necessarily* returns `loading` as `true`, giving no control to the test-writer whether to skip that state (which obviously I would like tot do). Note that when `useQuery` returns `loading` to be `true`, rendering my component will error out, since it's destructuring `data`, which is undefined. Because of this, I can never make it past that loading state without the test failing.

Here's my test code:

```
it("works", async () => {
  (useCurrentVampId as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(
    () => "6070dedd58d7bf715eb2a6c5"
  );
  const component = mount(
    <MockedProvider
      mocks={[
        {
          request: {
            query: COUNT_OFF_ADAPTER_QUERY,
            variables: {
              vampId: "6070dedd58d7bf715eb2a6c5"
            }
          },
          result: {
            data: {
              vamp: {
                id: "6070dedd58d7bf715eb2a6c5",
                countingOff: true,
                countingOffStartTime: 1234
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]}
      addTypename={false}
    >
      <CountOffAdapter></CountOffAdapter>
    </MockedProvider>
  );
  await wait(0);
  component.update();
});
```

I'm curious if there's a way to hack around this. It would be nice if you could specify `loading: false` in the query mock, but you can't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **Next.js** and I mostly do server-side rendering, so I ran into the same situation as you and I decided to investigate a bit further. It seems like apollo-client offers delay prop in the actual mock, e.g:

```
const mock: MockedResponse = {
  request: {
    query: SomeDocument,
    variables: { slug: 'test' },
  },
  result: { data: fakeData },
  delay: 0, // <---------THIS ----------|(number or undefined)
};
```

But this also didn't help, so I went deeper into the source code and everything became clear after I saw the following:

```js
 return new Observable(observer => {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (configError) {
          try {
            // The onError function can return false to indicate that
            // configError need not be passed to observer.error. For
            // example, the default implementation of onError calls
            // observer.error(configError) and then returns false to
            // prevent this extra (harmless) observer.error call.
            if (this.onError(configError, observer) !== false) {
              throw configError;
            }
          } catch (error) {
            observer.error(error);
          }
        } else if (response) {
          if (response.error) {
            observer.error(response.error);
          } else {
            if (response.result) {
              observer.next(
                typeof response.result === 'function'
                  ? (response.result as ResultFunction<FetchResult>)()
                  : response.result
              );
            }
            observer.complete();
          }
        }
      }, response && response.delay || 0);
```

As you can see here, the delay is only used as a milliseconds argument to the setTimeout, which is an async code -> means will be added after the sync code in the javascript **queue** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop). So, it doesn't really matter what value you provide for the delay field.

Final conclusion to your question: There's **no way** to skip the loading state as of now.